# Renaming the key in a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts:

```
[{"id" : "2016_a",
"data_1" : 106,
"data_2" : 200},
{"id" : "2015_a",
"data_1" : 110,
"data_2" : 105}
]
```

I wish to take the `id` record and use it to create a single, unique list of dicts, such that:

```
[{"data_1_2016_a" : 106,
"data_1_2015_a" : 110,
"data_2_2016_a" : 200,
"data_2_2015_a" : : 105}]
```

How do I append the string `id` to the `key` value of each other record?

Comment: Why do you want the result to be a list consisting of a single dict, rather than just a dict on its own?

Comment: No strong reason - either would be fine.

Comment: Is there a colon in the first `id`?

Comment: There was, but there shouldn't be! ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's simple to loop through and assign.

```
 result = {}
 for elem in data:
     for k, v in elem.items():
        if k != 'id':
             result['{}_{}'.format(elem['id'], k)] = v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use *dictionary comprehension*:

```
result = {dic['id']+'_'+k:v for dic in dictionaries
                            for k,v in dic.items() if k != 'id'}
```

You can (probably) improve efficiency a bit by using a generator inside:

```
result = {dicid+k:v for dic,dicid in ((_dic,_dic['id']+'_') for _dic in dictionaries)
                    for k,v in dic.items() if k != 'id'}
```

Here we save on lookups (`dic['id']`) and we also have to append the underscore only once. This results in:

```
>>> {dicid+k:v for dic,dicid in ((_dic,_dic['id']+'_') for _dic in dictionaries)
...                     for k,v in dic.items() if k != 'id'}
{'2016_a_data_1': 106, '2015_a_data_2': 105, '2016_a_data_2': 200, '2015_a_data_1': 110}
```

Comment: just change `dic['id']+k` into `k+'_'+dic['id']` and you'll match his request.